# Fatal Exception: NSRangeException

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have not been able to repo this issue. I understand what NSRangeException represents but I do not understand why it may occur when creating a nib file. This is the crash report I receive from Crashlytics:

```
Fatal Exception: NSRangeException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x1912fefd8 __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x18fd60538 objc_exception_throw
2  CoreFoundation                 0x1912efcf4 -[__NSArrayM removeObjectsInRange:]
3  UIKit                          0x197936dd4 +[NSBundle(UINSBundleLocalizableStringAdditions) popNibPath]
4  UIKit                          0x197934d44 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:]
5  ProjectName                    0x10019e114 static ClassFoo.instanceFromNib() -> ClassFoo (ClassFoo.swift:155)
```

This is my call:

```
return UINib(nibName: "ClassFoo", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)[0] as! ClassFoo
```

How can UINib NOT have a count > 0?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that you're using the correct xib name and bundle?

Comment: Yes, it's correct. The app works as expected with that xib.

Comment: And there's actually a view in that nib file?

Comment: Yes. I've been using this particular nib for a long time without issues. I didn't have any recent changes to the file either, nor has this issue ever been reported any other time using the same build.

Comment: So I expect a range of 1 for that one object to be returned from my main bundle, but in this particular case it came back 0, causing the exception.

Comment: The crash is not from the attempt to access element 0 from the nib. The crash is happening inside the call to `instantiateWithOwner`. The nib is failing to load due to an issue finding the path in the bundle.

Comment: How does it fail to find the path to an object in the main bundle on one occasion and not others?

Answer (score -1):

I think this error may be caused by the [0] in your code. Thanks.

Comment: Well, yeah. OP's question is _how_ a 0-th element could be missing.